# What to do if a title is not best format, but my edits get rejected by the OP's poster?

Tags: discussion

[How many kills do you need to get before leveling up a trait in Star Wars Battlefront?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/259293/88641)

I atempted to remove the games name from the title, since afaik those don't belong into the title, sicne thats what tags are for.
I also noted exactly that explanation into the edit notes.

But OP's poster rejected the edit.

What to do in such a situation?
(In case in this particular case I'm wrong and it is fine if he wants to keep the games name in the title, assume another example where he is wrong, when answering.)

Comment: I don't see any problem with the title and feel you are being too picky.

Comment: @rom016: Whats wrong about beeing too picky? I mean I'm not blaming him for doing it. Nor I would downvote because of this. But there are rules. And what ever how picky it might be, whats wrong if one "helps"(mpov) others making their posts more fitting into the concept?

Comment: Being too picky give a clique image to the site and drives people away. I have left other sites for this reason. Sorry if I my self am coming over picky. I should be going to bed.

Comment: @rom016: All is fine. I wouldn't call it even "picky" but strict. And I guess thats a image this whole network is intended to represent (I may be wrong but don't think so.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't get into a rollback war over it. In general, placing the game title in the question isn't *necessary*, but when it's done organically as part of a sentence, as it is here, it's fine and even preferable for some people. Such an edit absolutely qualifies as "too minor" to be worth fighting over.

(The more problematic situation is when the title is simply appended to the front of the question as some kind of prefix. In those cases it *should* be fixed, but again, rollback wars are bad. Leave a comment, and, if necessary flag a mod to resolve the situation if need be.)

Comment: +1. The key thing here is that the game's name was used _organically as part of a sentence_ (I couldn't word that any better than what you did!). This would be different if the title was "Star Wars Battlefront: how many kills ..."

Comment: I will add that I really, really wish certain sites (this one and RPG.SE especially) would reconsider this policy.  I get "that's what tags are for", but I typically discover interesting things by browsing the related questions from my favorite recent questions - and related questions (and Hot Network Questions) don't display their tags.  I've been half an hour into research for an answer before I notice that the tag I thought was obvious from the title isn't actually on the question and it's about a different game than I thought altogether.

Answer (score -4):

Tags are meta-details for *categorising content*. You should be able to remove them altogether and still have a question which makes sense. They should not be relied on for anything except to encourage related questions to appear in the sidebar.

Game names absolutely should be mentioned somewhere other than tags, either in the body of the question or in the title (or, indeed, both).

Titles should read as *titles*, not as tags, and the title in your example does indeed read as a title. It’s an excellent title as is, and your edit was actively harmful, removing good information for no reason.

Comment: Ew, no.  This goes against our entire tag policy.

Comment: Its fair to say this might be the case on the exchanges you frequent; however, that is not the case, here. Game titles in the title are neither required nor against policy.